# Implementation of traversing of chunk partition in PLINQ

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, plinq

I came across on implementation `ContiguousChunkLazyEnumerator` class, which is used by PLINQ (traversing of chunk is performed with this iterator). `MoveNext` method uses thread safe access to source `IEnumerator` (by using speficied `lock`), moreover, it saves results of access to internal buffer. It is brief piece of code:

```
lock (m_sourceSyncLock)
{
// Some .net stuff
    try
    {
        for (; i < mutables.m_nextChunkMaxSize && m_source.MoveNext(); i++)
        {
        // Read the current entry into our buffer.
        chunkBuffer[i] = m_source.Current;
        }
    }
// Some .net stuff
}
```

Such iterator will be used by worker threads (N worker threads work with the same iterator). But I really don't understand benefits of such parallel approach. Usage of `lock` in this context should kill any performance benefits. My assumption is that sequal access by the only worker thread should work with the same speed.

Answer (score 3):

This is because using PLINQ optimizes for concurrent processing of the items, not for the concurrent enumeration of the items.

The heavy `lock` is done per chunk, so multiple threads will yield to each other between chunks.

This really shines when you have an `IEnumerable` that is quick to enumerate (like `List<T>` for example, in reality, there are internal optimisations for `List<T>`, so not the best example), and want to do some slow computational work on the results.

This code is about creating partitioned data to then be consumed by multiple threads. While it is thread-safe, it is not supposed to be about the fastest concurrent enumeration. It is optimised for data locality.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I don't see concurrent computation of items of collection (lock kills performance). Simple note - List<T> will be processed by range partition instead of chunk partition.

Comment: Yes, I did mention the `List<T>` optimization. I mean this code is about creating partitioned data to then be consumed by multiple threads. While it is thread-safe, it is not supposed to be about the fastest concurrent enumeration. It is optimised for data locallity.